# How do I get IPv6 packets to my KVM virtual machine?

Tags: debian, virtualization, routing, kvm-virtualization, ipv6

My setup is:

Debian Wheezy x64 on the host and on the guest.

I am using a tun/tap setup to connect a virtual machine to the host.

The KVM network options I use are:

```
-net nic,macaddr=DE:AD:BE:EF:1A:DC
-net tap,ifname=tap3,script=no,downscript=no
```

IPv4 networking works using NAT, so I can ssh into the machine from the outside just fine.

IPv6 is another story.

The host has full IPv6 connectivity, I can reach it from the outside and I can reach outside IPv6 hosts.

Host /etc/network/interfaces (IPv6 part)

```
iface eth0 inet6 static
  address 2a01:...::2
  netmask 64
  gateway fe80::1
```

Guest /etc/network/interfaces (IPv6 part)

```
iface eth0 inet6 static
  address 2a01:...::3
  netmask 64
  gateway route add 2a01:...::1:3
```

The `tap3` interface is setup this way:

```
ip -6 addr add 2a01:...::1:3/64 dev tap3 # The tap3 address
ip -6 route add 2a01:...::3 dev tap3 # The guest eth0 address
ip -6 route add 2a01:...::2 dev tap3 # The host eth0 address
```

The host can reach `2a01:...:3`.

The guest can reach `2a01:...::1:3` and even 
`2a01:...::2`, but no address outside the host.

```
ping6 www.google.de
PING www.google.de(fra07s32-in-x1f.1e100.net) 56 data bytes
^C
--- www.google.de ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 3024ms
```

The packets get lost, there is no ICMP response. (From the host it works as expected)

I have enabled forwarding on sysctl:

```
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.forwarding = 1
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.mc_forwarding = 0
net.ipv6.conf.tap3.forwarding = 1
net.ipv6.conf.tap3.mc_forwarding = 0
```

How do I get packets through the host?

**Edit**: "..." is always the same value for all addresses in the above file and command listings. It's the /64 network that I got from RIPE.

Comment: I have a similar setup at home which works without trouble.  Is it right that the host is the router for the guest?  Then you must install and run radvd on the host.  Just to make sure, could you run `ip -6 route` in the guest?

Comment: It is not easy to help, when you are not including the full IPv6 addresses. It is particular difficult because you left out those parts of the address, that most people get wrong. Many people mix up link prefix and routed prefix. The difference between those two prefixes is found towards the end of the network part of the address, which means it is just before the middle of the IPv6 address.

Comment: @kasperd All addresses use the same address prefix (the global /64 network that I have been assigned).

Comment: @countermode I have also enabled `ndp_proxy` in the kernel, do I still need `radvd`?

Comment: The host should act as the router for the guest.

Comment: [ndp_proxy] Oh dear... no, not in that case - I guess. I have no experience with that. All I can tell you is that my setup with radvd works. Anyway, I think proxying is a crutch; security wise you enlarge the attack radius against the neighbor discovery and technically it just doesn't "smell" right. I really would consider radvd, it's easy to configure and makes no noticeable overhead.

Comment: And libvirt will do radvd for you automatically...but for some reason you don't seem to be using it? Also, using a tap interface for this is quite strange. Are you using Hetzner?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Yes, I'm using Hetzner

Comment: @JensMühlenhoff Do you mean `proxy_ndp`? I tested `proxy_ndp` at some time and didn't manage to get it work. I think `ndppd` looks promising, but I haven't tested it (since I had written my own daemon for the purpose, before I learned about `ndppd`). I suggest you contact your provider and ask them for a routed prefix. There simply doesn't exist any good reason for them not giving you at least a `/60`. If asking for a routed prefix doesn't help, then I would suggest testing out `ndppd` as a workaround.

Comment: @JensMühlenhoff If you configure each VM with a static IPv6 configuration, then you should be able to get it working without `radvd`. Besides, if you don't get a routed prefix, then SLAAC is not practical. So autoconfig would have to be done using DHCPv6. It may be simpler for you to configure each VM statically rather than using `radvd` and `DHCPv6`.

Comment: @kasperd Yes `proxy_ndp` (typo), I'm starting to think that the router of the data center is at fault.

Comment: @JensMühlenhoff No reason to blame the router. You are trying to do something, which Hetzner does not support. Arguably, they should support it, but they don't. You can work around it, as long as you get your host to respond to all the neighbor discovery requests. That your host isn't responding to the neighbor discovery requests isn't the fault of the router. I say forget about `proxy_ndp` and use something better. But ask for a routed prefix first, because a routed prefix would make the entire setup cleaner, more efficient, and easier to work with.

Comment: @kasperd I will ask for a routed prefix, thanks for your input.